# How to create a one to many relationship without primary key in SQL Server or Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have 2 tables as shown here:

Table `A`:

```
 [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [AName] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
```

Table `B`:

```
 [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ANameID] [uniqueidentifier] UNIQUE NOT NULL
```

I want to create a one-to-many relationship between `B` and `A` where the `ANameID` in the `B` table can reference one or more rows in the `A` table using the `AName` column in the `A` table. The `A.AName` column is NOT the primary key.

There can be many rows in TABLE A with the same AName value, but only one row in TABLE B with the ANameID value.

How can I implement this either in SQL or in EF?

Comment: You just need to add a foreign key to `ROADS` in the `INTERSECTION` then.

Comment: I think you will probably need a Many-to-many relationship here. If you are actually designing a database for Roads and Intersections then One Road can have many intersections and also One Intersection will have Many roads.

Comment: Please disregard the table names. Roads and intersections may have been poor choices for names.

Comment: _There can be many rows in TABLE A with the same AName value_ That makes your goal utter nonsense as far as a "relationship" goes. Given a specific value for name, a given row in table B will join (or refer or whatever term is appropriate) to multiple rows in table A. It does not help you or your reader to associate column AName in table A with column ANameID in table B. I think you are likely confusing yourself and your readers with a unclear goal.

Comment: It's called "one-to-many"

Comment: In fact, https://stackoverflow.com/users/7926183/smor, what I describe is pretty much a textbook description of a one-to-many relationship: "In relational databases, a one-to-many relationship occurs when a parent record in one table can potentially reference several child records in another table." (From https://www.techopedia.com/definition/25122/one-to-many-relationship). So, I am very sorry that you are confused, but I don't think the other readers are.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a Unique Index on RoadId in table Roads then you can create a Foreign Key.

However, two thoughts:

1. Why not put a PK on Roads? Could be RoadId...
2. Given that an intersection should a minimum of two things, your
   design is not complete as presented. I assume that this is on
   purpose, but just thought I'd mention it...

Comment: Yes, I omitted all unnecessary columns in both tables.

Comment: The whole point is that there can be multiple rows in Table A with the same value in the column AName, so declaring that column UNIQUE won't work.